Use python to automatically post on Instagram
I am using instabot package on python to build an app that automatically post photos on my profile.
This is the code I wrote
from instabot import Bot
import configparser



# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
username = str(config['Instagram']['user'])
password = str(config['Instagram']['password'])



bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=username, password=password)
bot.upload_photo("./pic.png", caption="caption")
bot.logout()

the problem is that I get the error
2024-08-03 19:01:54,188 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2024-08-03 19:01:54,754 - ERROR - Request returns 429 error!
2024-08-03 19:01:54,754 - WARNING - That means 'too many requests'. I'll go to sleep for 5 minutes.

How can I solve it? Can I use another package?

Send fewer requests per time or pay more money to Instagram to be allowed to send more requests per time.

Just for your reference, the limit is 50 API-generated posts per 24-hour period.

@mkrieger1 I just runned the code and this is the error, I did not send multiple requests. This is the whole code

@TimRoberts I did not post anything, this is the first time I run the code and I obtained this error

This does not appear to be using the official API - otherwise, it would not be using username and password directly. So this can only be some sort of script that tries to use frontend functionality - but gets caught at the login part already.

If you are talking about posting to an IG professional account - there is an API for that, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-graph-api/content-publishing

upload_photo is making a post.

Crosslink on Reddit.

have you tired instagram-private-api? You can use pip to install it

Please be aware that there is no official Instagram API for personal accounts. Attempting to automate them will likely get you banned or suspended for bot activity. https://www.facebook.com/help/instagram/740480200552298/

Try to use selenium instead of that by doing what you want with some automated clicks.

The error message is quite clear, and is coming from the server. Not sure why you think a different library would change anything?

I solved my problem by changing the python package and using Instagrapi.
This is the sample code that should work
from instagrapi import Client
from instagrapi.exceptions import LoginRequired
import os


username = "YOUR USERNAME"
password = "YOUR PASSWORD"

cl = Client()

# Load session if it exists, otherwise login and save session
try:
    cl.load_settings("./instagram_session.json") # INSERT YOUR SESSION MAE

except FileNotFoundError:
    cl.login(username, password)
    cl.dump_settings("./instagram_session.json")

except LoginRequired:
    if os.path.exists("../sessions/instagram_session.json"):
        os.remove("../sessions/instagram_session.json")

    print("Login required, old session deleted.")
    cl.login(username, password)
    cl.dump_settings("./instagram_session.json")


print(cl.account_info().dict())
media = cl.photo_upload("../hello.jpg", caption="hello")
media_id = media.dict()["id"]
cl.media_comment(media_id, "leave a comment")
media_pk = media.dict()["media"]["pk"]


The library you are currently using was archived by the owner on Feb 25, 2024. The link was on the official download page of pypi, checkout the Project links heading at left panel.
For time being you can use another package : instagrapi
Here is a sample code:-
from instagrapi import Client
from instagrapi.exceptions import LoginRequired
import configparser

# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
username = str(config['Instagram']['user'])
password = str(config['Instagram']['password'])

# Create a Client instance
client = Client()

try:
    # Login to Instagram
    client.login(username, password)
    
    # Upload a photo with a caption
    client.photo_upload("./pic.png", caption="Your caption here")
    
except LoginRequired:
    print("Login required. Please check your credentials.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
finally:
    # Logout from Instagram
    client.logout()

